# How to create multiple selects in Rails and haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, haml

I have a table with data as shown

```
id | Resource | Access
___________________________
1 | Fee records | can_read
2 | Fee records | no_access
3 | Fee records | can_write
4 | Class register | can_read
5 | Class register | no_access
6 | Class register | can_write
```

I wish to create a haml select such that I will have the `resource` on the left and the `access` as options of the select. Something like

```
Fee records -> [can_read, no_access, can_write]
Class register -> [can_read, no_access, can_write]
```

When a user selects `can_read` option under `Fee Records` I wish to get back id `1` from the table above, when `no_access` option under `Class register` is selected, I wish to get id `6`. So basically I will have two selects but the options selected have to return the id from the table above. The `resource` should also not be duplicated. In this case, only `Fee records` and `Class register` should be on the left with the respective options as a dropdown on the right. How would I achieve this on Ruby on Rails and haml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to solve the issue above. In the controller's new method, I had

```
def new
 @permissions = ["no_access", "can_read", "can_write"]
 @unique_permissions = Model.select(:resource).map(&:resource).uniq
end
```

The line `@unique_permissions = Model.select(:resource).map(&:resource).uniq` helps me get unique values from the table above, so I'll have a collection of `[Fee_records, Class_register]`

In the haml, I will have

```
- @unique_permissions.each do |permission|
      .row
        .col-md-4
          = permission
        = f.select permission, @permissions, {}, class: "form-control col-md-8"
```

This will give me two selects with `@permissions` the array containing `["no_access", "can_read", "can_write"]` as the options of each select.
In the controller, I will permit the params which will be `Fee_records` and `Class_register`
In the create action, I will get `permission_keys` from the params, basically to get [Fee_records, Class_register] as the keys.
To get the specific id related to the option selected by the user, I will loop through the keys like

```
permission_keys.each do |permission|
  permission_id = Model.find_by(
    resource: permission, access: permission_params[:permission]
   ).id
  # other code
end
```